# Чтение файла с пагинацией

Tags: php, файлы, логирование

Я пишу модуль, который должен брать логи сайта по api, выводить список сайтов с функцией удаления - с этим проблем нет. Но должен быть функционал для открытия файла, чтобы посмотреть что там. Файл лога может быть большим, из-за чего php будет упираться в память и падать. Поэтому я думаю, можно ли читать файл по типу пагинации? Первая страница - от 0 до 100 строки (например), сохраняем строку и при переходе по пагинации передаем метку для чтения - от 100 до 200 строки. Думал использовать fread, там есть ограничение чтения по байтам, но опять же, как указать начальный байт, с которого будет начинаться чтение? В общем жду ваших предложений

Comment: Запомнить, сколько байт/строк было прочитано и при следующем чтении игнорировать первые N байт/строк =)

Answer (score 0):

Использовать file_get_contents. Предпоследний параметр функции это позиция элемента строки, с которого начинается чтение. Последний параметр это позиция элемента строки, до которого будет читаться файл. При чтении первого фрагмента 0-1000 (то есть берем 1000 элементов строки), сохраняем по который элемент читали, при следующем запросе плюсуем 1000 к началу чтения и читаем с 1000 по 2000 элемент